# Why am I getting a segmentation fault error whenever I'm trying to run this LinkedList delete function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program to delete a node at the N'th position of a linked list. According to the output, it should be:

```
George
Betty
Felix
Renee

George 
Betty
Felix

George
Felix

Felix
```

When running on repl.it (my submission website), it brings up that I am getting a segmentation error. However, when I run it off my personal computer on CodeBlocks, it runs without errors, however, it only outputs the first line which is `George`, `Betty`, `Felix`, and `Renee` without deleting and re-outputting.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    string name;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head;

class LinkedList {
  public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void push(string);
    void output();
    void remove(int);

  private:
    Node *first;
};


void LinkedList::remove(int n)
{
  struct Node* temp1 = head;
  if(n == 1)
  {
    head = temp1 -> next;
    delete(temp1);
    return;
  }
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
  {
    temp1 = temp1 -> next;
  }
  struct Node* temp2 = temp1 -> next;
  temp1 -> next = temp2 -> next;
  delete(temp2);

}


LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
  first = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
  Node *current=first;

  while(current!=NULL)
  {
    Node *ptr=current;
    current = current->next;
    delete(ptr);
  }
}

void LinkedList::push(string data)
{
  Node *temp;

  temp = new Node;
  (*temp).name = data;
  (*temp).next = first;
  first = temp;
}

void LinkedList::output()
{
  Node *current = first;

  while(current!=NULL)
  {
    cout << (*current).name << endl;
    current = (*current).next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {
  LinkedList students;

  students.push("Renee");
  students.push("Felix");
  students.push("Betty");
  students.push("George");


  students.output();

  students.remove(3);
  students.output();

  students.remove(1);
  students.output();

  students.remove(0);
  students.output();


}
```

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain." -- Scotty, Star Trek III. The `remove()` function is unnecessarily complicated, and has several fundamental flaws. If you use your debugger to run it, one line at a time, the bugs should be obvious. Instead of trying to patch around them, why not do this right in the first place? The correct solution should be no more than just five or six lines of code. One loop finds the element to delete (first node, or any other node in the list, same logic). Three more statement to relink the list, and delete the node. Done.

Comment: Your push updates the member `first` ; it does **not** update `head` (a suspicious global variable of questionable origin). Now, consider that little gem of information while reviewing the code in your `remove` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for everything *but* `LinkedList::remove` manages the list via the `first` member variable. But `LinkedList::remove` references `head`, a suspiciously otherwise-unused global variable. I'm confident that shouldn't even be in the code at all.

Delete the global `head`, and change `LinkedList::remove` to be:

```
void LinkedList::remove(int n)
{
    Node **pp = &first;
    while (*pp && n-- > 1)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp)
    {
        Node *tmp = *pp;
        *pp = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @cliffclimber pay close attention to the pointer-to-pointer trick being used here. It can also be applied throughout the linked list member functions to eliminate special cases and generally simplify the book-keeping. The key understanding you should come away with is that `first` is simply a `next` pointer with a different name. The extra level of pointer indirection hides this single difference.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is unclear what is this declaration

```
Node* head;
```

doing in the program.

The class `Node` should be declared within the class `LinkedList` and should be inaccessible for users of the list.

In C++ indices start from 0. So it would be better if you would count indices in the list also starting from 0. The type of the parameter `n` of the function remove should have unsigned integer type for example the type `size_t`.

You did not check within function whether a current pointer is equal to nullptr. So the function has undefined behavior.

Moreover instead of the data member `first` the function refers to the global variable `head`.

```
struct Node* temp1 = head;
```

It seems you copied and pastes somewhere (in the internet) a C code of singly linked list ant tried to update it.

The code of the function can be very simple if to use pointer to pointer. For example

```
void LinkedList::remove( size_t n )
{
    Node **current = &first;

    while ( n-- != 0 && *current != nullptr )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    if ( *current != nullptr )
    {
        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Indices passed to the function start from 0 as it should be in a C++ program.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class LinkedList 
{
public:
    LinkedList() = default;
    LinkedList( const LinkedList & ) = delete;
    LinkedList & operator =( const LinkedList & ) = delete;

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        }           
    }

    void push( const std::string &s )
    {
        head = new Node { s, head };
    }

    bool remove( size_t n )
    {
        Node **current = &head;
        while ( n-- != 0 && *current != nullptr )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        bool success = *current != nullptr;

        if ( success )
        {
            delete std::exchange( *current, ( *current )->next );
        }

        return success;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const LinkedList &list )
    {
        for ( Node *current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->name << " -> ";
        }

        return os << "null";
    }

private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string name;
        Node* next;
    } *head = nullptr;
};

int main() 
{
     LinkedList students;

    students.push("Renee");
    students.push("Felix");
    students.push("Betty");
    students.push("George");

    std::cout << students << '\n';

    students.remove(3);
    std::cout << students << '\n';

    students.remove(1);
    std::cout << students << '\n';

    students.remove(0);
    std::cout << students << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
George -> Betty -> Felix -> Renee -> null
George -> Betty -> Felix -> null
George -> Felix -> null
Felix -> null
```